# Are stable isotopes ever used in pharmaceuticals?

Tags: biochemistry, pharmacology

Carbon has two stable isotopes, C-12 and C-13. Since they both have the same electronic structure they can both make up the same molecules, but presumably they may perform different functions in biochemistry due to different mass.

**Q: Have various stable isotopes of the same atom ever been put to use in pharmacology?**

Basic internet research only yielded information about unstable, or radioactive isotopes.

Comment: I think you'll find that the chemistry is more important than the mass,  but I don't know if there has been any pharmaceutical made that that specifically used a stable isotope, so not writing this as an answer.

Comment: @bob1 MRI works on precession of the nuclear spin, and that varies dramatically. Consider 12C (spin 0, no (useful) magnetic moment) vs 13C (spin 1/2 like a proton, but heavier) Now whether medically approved contrast agents used in human MRI are considered a pharmaceutical *per se* or not is a different question.

Comment: [29Si Isotope-Enriched Silicon Nanoparticles for an Efficient Hyperpolarized Magnetic Resonance Imaging Probe](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsami.1c16617) and [Use of 13C Isotopes in MR Research](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/TW/en/technical-documents/technical-article/analytical-chemistry/nuclear-magnetic-resonance/isotopes-in-mr-research) and [MRI/MRS: Use of Isotopes in Hyperpolarization](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/TW/en/technical-documents/technical-article/analytical-chemistry/calibration-qualification-and-validation/mri-mrs_use-of-isotopes-in-hyperpolarization)

Comment: @uhoh It looks as if the FDA considers them to be  [intravenous drugs](https://www.fda.gov/drugs/postmarket-drug-safety-information-patients-and-providers/information-gadolinium-based-contrast-agents), so, yes, pharmaceuticals

Comment: @SimonCrase excellent! The last task of showing that stable isotopes are *used* as pharmaceuticals (rather than just explored as possible candidates) remains and I'm probably not quailed to assert that with supporting sources. Perhaps someone else can/will. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh I didn't think of contrast agents; wouldn't have thought they are pharma, but apparently they are.

Comment: @bob1 well if someone is going to inject a substance into your blood, you'd like it to be safe, and therefore its manufacture and distribution carefully regulated. Doesn't really matter whether it's for diagnosis or treatment.

Comment: Could you change the actual Question title to reflect the explanation in the exposition, Q: Have various stable isotopes of the same atom ever been put to use in pharmacology?

Either way, isn't the real Question, 'Have different isotopes of the same atoms been used in pharmacology?' and isn't the different wording in both title and exposition simply confusing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check the Wiki articles:

- [Isotopes in Medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_in_medicine)
- [Radiopharmaceutical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiopharmaceutical)

If we solely focus on carbon-13 based drugs then there is [carbon-13 labeled ibrutinib](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36412065/), [carbon-13 labeled midazolam/1′-hydroxymidazolam](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040403905001978), [carbon-13 labelled aspirin](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/4465004/).

Lastly, you can reads this papers:

1. Schellekens RC, Stellaard F, Woerdenbag HJ, Frijlink HW, Kosterink JG. *Applications of stable isotopes in clinical pharmacology.* Br J Clin Pharmacol. **2011** Dec;72(6):879-97. doi: [10.1111/j.1365-2125.2011](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3244634/)
2. Gregg, C.T. *Some application of stable isotopes in clinical pharmacology*. Eur J Clin Pharmacol 7, 315–319 (**1974**). DOI: [10.1007/BF00560350](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00560350)
3. Bodamer OAF, Halliday D, *Uses of stable isotopes in clinical diagnosis and research in the paediatric population*, Archives of Disease in Childhood **2001;84**:444-448, DOI: [10.1136/adc.84.5.444](https://adc.bmj.com/content/84/5/444)

Answer (score 27):

[Deutetrabenazine.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutetrabenazine)

As the linked article from Wikipedia notes:

> Deutetrabenazine (trade name Austedo) is a vesicular monoamine
> transporter 2 inhibitor which is used for the treatment of chorea
> associated with Huntington's disease and tardive dyskinesia.
>
> Chemically, deutetrabenazine is an isotopic isomer of tetrabenazine in
> which six hydrogen atoms have been replaced by deuterium atoms. The
> incorporation of deuterium slows the rate of drug metabolism, allowing
> less frequent dosing.

Whilst what you have in the above is an isotope of hydrogen, the effect this gives is seen in other compounds belonging to the [bioisosteres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioisostere) (chemical substituents or groups with similar physical or chemical properties which produce broadly similar biological properties in the same chemical compound), the purpose being to:

> enhance the desired biological or physical properties of a compound
> without making significant changes in chemical structure

The different mass of the deuterium in the case of deutetrabenzine is thought to [tweak the chemistry](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1965JChPh..42.2683B/abstract) in useful ways:

> However, the C–D bond is a bit shorter, and it has reduced
> electronic polarizability and less hyperconjugative stabilization of
> adjacent bonds, including developing an anti-bonding orbital as part
> of the newly formed bond. This can potentially result in weaker van
> der Waals stabilization, and can produce other changes in properties
> that are difficult to predict, including changes in the intramolecular
> volume and the transition state volume

Answer (score 16):

The [urea breath test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urea_breath_test) for Helicobacter pylori uses urea labelled with carbon-13 or carbon-14 to detect the presence of the bacteria, which would metabolize it to carbon dioxide and be exhaled.